# Sparql query for display list of movies

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to retrieve the titles of movies on http://id.dbpedia.org/page/Daftar_film_Indonesia but there is nothing on the list

I tried this queries, it runs but with no results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE{
?p dbpedia-owl:Movies <http://id.dbpedia.org/resource/Daftar_film_Indonesia>.
}
```

what queries i can use to retrive all title of the movies ?

Comment: I guess you should learn the structure of DBpedia first. I mean, based on what did you create the query here? `dbpedia-owl:Movies` is a class in DBpedia. so you can't use it as predicate of a triple pattern - or at least it doesn't make sense and will lead to an empty resultset. Moreover, you have to read again about RDF, if you want to get something about the given resource like the titles, it's supposed to be the subject of the RDF triples + you have to use the correct property that assigns the titles to the resource.

Comment: So, which property leads to the titles? I can only see `rdfs:label` - is that what you mean by "title"? Or what else do you expect as result?

Comment: or do you need those links: `SELECT ?o WHERE{
<http://id.dbpedia.org/resource/Daftar_film_Indonesia> dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink ?o
}`?

Comment: hey thank you for the answer, it help me a lot, yes i need those link for retrive information about the director, title of movie, and starring, btw when i tried this query why the result is not the list link of the movie ?

`SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE{
?p dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink <http://id.dbpedia.org/resource/Daftar_film_Indonesia>.
}`

Comment: what do you mean by *"list link of the movie"* ?